How to host a website with 2 CMS under the same domain with Nginx?
For some reason, I have to build a website with WordPress + TYPO3 in same domain name. And following is my Nginx config.
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    access_log /var/www/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/error.log;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        root /var/www/wordpress;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;

            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
    location ~ ^/(sign-up|login|others) {
        root /var/www/typo3;

        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                return 404;
            }

            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
            fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 240s;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 240s;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 240s;

            fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;

            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}

As you can see, the WordPress will be for most cases, and only some specific pages are from TYPO3. However, the result is, when I visit http://example.com/sign-up in my browser, it doesn't take me to TYPO3, but WordPress. Did I do anything wrong?
BTW, if I change / to root /var/www/typo3;, it works, and I can get the sign-up page from TYPO3.

So it appears that your "BTW" comment holds the answer. Or there's any other issue with it?

Actually, the "BTW" is to show that I have both WP and TYPO3 setup correctly and working, but it doesn't help with my problem.
